# Print all Segues used in iOS App

Tags: uistoryboardsegue

I have a list of Buildtime warnings and several of them are related to Deprecated Push Segues (Push segues are deprecated since iOS 8.0).
I am unable to find these segues within the Storyboard because all segues are already in Show (e.g Push) kind.

Is it possible to print all existing segues via Xcode console?